# htaccess 301 redirect /%C2%A0/

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to do a 301 redirect via htaccess from `http://www.domainname.co.uk/%C2%A0/` to `http://www.domainname.co.uk/` but i can not get it to work

I am having a lot of trouble with the `/%C2%A0/` any help with this would be great

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\xC2\xA0/?$ / [L,R=301]
```

Or if you have to use mod_alias:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/\xC2\xA0/?$ /
```

Comment: Hi Thank you so much for your help RedirectMatch 301 ^/\xC2\xA0/?$ / fixed the problem for me. thanks again.